# How to find my tweets where a specific user retweeted it?

Tags: twitter, followers

I want to know if a specific user ever retweeted any of my tweets.

For example: `from:@username includes:nativeretweets filter:nativeretweets`

The above command gets part of what I want, but I need the output to show only my tweets. I thought the command below might work but it does not return any results.

```
from:@username to:MyUserName include:nativeretweets filter:nativeretweets
```

Answer (score 0):

One query which partially seems to work is

```
from:username filter:nativeretweets @MyUserName
```

I mentioned partially because this also includes tweets retweeted by *username* which mention *@MyUserName*. Not necessarily tweeted by *MyUserName*. Also, this only seems to show recent retweets because that's twitter search for you ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ It's broken most of the times.

---

You could also use [Tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/) to filter specific notifications:

- Select *Add Column* from the left panel and select *Notifications*
- Click on the the top right icon to filter for specific notification

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- Under *Notification types*, select only *Retweets*

  [image]
- Under *Tweet authors*, select *"specific user..."* and enter the *username*

  [image]

This also excluded tweets for some users. But, way better than the twitter native search.